# React router error "useRoutes() may be used only in the contect of a <Router> component."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

So, I was making this website when I saw these BIG red errors in the console ( I know a nightmare :( )
The error said this:

```
Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

And I didn't even use a "useRoutes" hook.
Anyways here's my code:

```
import Links from "./components/Links"
import Addition from "./pages/Addition"
import "./styles/App.css"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Chose your operation:</h1>
      <div className="cards">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/addition" element={Addition} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Routes` component uses the `useRoutes`. `Routes` needs to be rendered within a routing context provided by a router component.

Additionally the `Addition` (*sorry, no pun intended*) needs to be passed to the `element` prop ***as JSX***. This was one of the breaking changes in the `Route` component API from v5 to v6.

Example:

```
import Links from "./components/Links"
import Addition from "./pages/Addition"
import "./styles/App.css"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router> // <-- render app into Router component
      <div>
        <h1>Chose your operation:</h1>
        <div className="cards">
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/addition"
              element={<Addition />} // <-- passed as JSX
            />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-error-useroutes-may-be-used-only-in-the-contect-of-a-router-co]

Comment: That gives me this error: Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.

Comment: @ArjunP Are you saying that wrapping the code in the `Router` *still* produces the same error? Can you edit the post to include the complete error message and code stacktrace? Can you also verify the installed version of `react-router-dom` by running `npm list react-router-dom`?

Comment: It says version 6.4.1, I think that's the correct version

Comment: @ArjunP Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-error-useroutes-may-be-used-only-in-the-contect-of-a-router-co-2t2mfv) demo. If you comment out the `Router` component in the render return it reproduces the error. This isn't to say that you don't have issues elsewhere in your app. Feel free to fork this sandbox and add in more of your code to see if you are able to reproduce the error, then we'll have something we can look at live.